# Indexing a matrix with predetermined rule

Tags: performance, matlab, matrix, indexing

I have `P <151x1 double>` and `D <6x1 double>`. An example of `D` would be `[24;7;9;11;10;12]`. I have to index `P` based on `D` such that in `P` I want to keep 6 blocks of 12 elements but each block is separated from the next block by `n` number of elements. `n` is given by `D`. The first 12 elements of `P` is the first block. Thus, the first block would be `P(1:12)`, the second block would be `P(37:48,1)` because we want to skip 24 elements after the first block (24 is `D(1,1)`, Third block to keep would be `P(56,1)` because we want to skip 7 elements after the second block (7 is `D(2,1)`), etc. After indexing I should end up with 72 elements.

Could anyone help me find a solution to indexing this efficiently?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One approach -

```
%// Parameters
block_size = 12;
num_blocks = 6;

step_add = [0 ; cumsum(D(1:num_blocks-1))];
start_ind = [0:block_size:block_size*(num_blocks-1)]'+1 + step_add; %//'
all_valid_ind = bsxfun(@plus,start_ind,0:block_size-1)'; %//'
out = P(all_valid_ind(:)); %// desired output
```

Please note that you won't be using the last element of D into the calculations, because each element of `D` defines the "gap" between consecutive blocks of elements that you are picking up from `P`.So you need only `5` elements to define `5` gaps between `6` blocks of elements .

---

## **Benchmarking**

Loop approach [from this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24645206/3293881):

```
function blocks = loop1(P,D)

blocks = zeros(12, numel(D)); % //Pre-allocate blocks matrix

%// We start accessing values at 1
startIndex = 1;
%// For each index in D
for idx = 1 : numel(D)
    %// Grab the 12 elements
    blocks(:,idx) = P(startIndex : startIndex + 11);
    %// Skip over 12 elements PLUS the number specified at D
    startIndex = startIndex + 12 + D(idx);
end

return;
```

No-loop approach (as discussed earlier in this solution):

```
function out = no_loop1(P,D)

%// Parameters
block_size = 12;
num_blocks = numel(D);

step_add = [0 ; cumsum(D(1:num_blocks-1))];
start_ind = [0:block_size:block_size*(num_blocks-1)]'+1 + step_add; %//'
all_valid_ind = bsxfun(@plus,start_ind,0:block_size-1)'; %//'
out = P(all_valid_ind(:)); %// desired output

return;
```

Actual benchmarking and plotting results:

```
P = rand(200000,1);
N_arr = [100 200 500 1000 2000 5000]; %// No. of D elements

timeall = zeros(2,numel(N_arr));
for k1 = 1:numel(N_arr)
    
    N = N_arr(k1);
    D = randi(10,N,1)+10;
    
    f = @() loop1(P,D);
    timeall(1,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
    f = @() no_loop1(P,D);
    timeall(2,k1) = timeit(f);
    clear f
    
end

figure,
hold on
plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:),'-ro')
plot(N_arr,timeall(2,:),'-kx')
legend('Loop Method','No-loop Method')
xlabel('Datasize (No. of D elements) ->')
ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
```

**Results**

[image]

**Conclusions**

No-loop approach as used in this solution looks the more efficient one across a varying range of datasizes.

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about using `cumsum`.

Comment: @rayryeng Yeah that part is crucial to doing this without loops.

Comment: I'm curious to see how this works in terms of timing

Comment: Just did some timing tests.  I iterated 100000 times, with `block_size=12`, `num_blocks=100`.  I took the average out of all 100000 times.  My method: 0.10849 ms, your method: 0.019366 ms, wandering star: 0.018405 ms. However, wandering star is missing indices 1 - 12 in his/her logic, and included unnecessary indices at the end of the matrix, so I'm benchmarking on a slightly incorrect solution.

Comment: Thank you, Divakar (and everyone else). This is great! Learned several things new today.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is using a [recurrence relation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recurrence_relation), the only option I can see is using `for` loops.  We must use output values from the previous iteration as input into the next iteration.  I personally can't see any technique in my arsenal that can do this vectorized.

If there is anyone else (Divakar, Luis Mendo, natan, Ben, Daniel, Amro, etc.) that can propose a more optimum solution, please feel free and answer.  Without further ado:

```
D = [24;7;9;11;10;12]; %// Define number of elements to skip over
blocks = zeros(12, numel(D)); % //Pre-allocate blocks matrix

%// We start accessing values at 1
startIndex = 1;
%// For each index in D
for idx = 1 : numel(D)
    %// Grab the 12 elements
    blocks(:,idx) = P(startIndex : startIndex + 11);
    %// Skip over 12 elements PLUS the number specified at D
    startIndex = startIndex + 12 + D(idx);
end
```

This should give you a `12 x 6` matrix, where each column corresponds to the set of elements you extracted from `P`.  As a small test, we can display the start and ending indices that we need to access `P` for extracting elements.  These are generated by replacing `blocks(:,idx) = ...`, with `disp([startIndex startIndex + 11]);` in the loop.  The indices generated are:

```
 1    12

37    48

56    67

77    88

100   111

122   133
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be vectorized, no problem.

```
    P = 1:200; % a generic P
    D = [24;7;9;11;10;12];

    D = [0 D(1:end-1)];

    basis = repmat(0:11, [6 1]);

    startingIndices = cumsum(D + 12) + 1;

    usefulIndices = bsxfun(@plus, basis, startingIndices);

    P(usefulIndices)
```

Without some more context, it's hard to suggest a method that indexes this "efficiently" -- if you're only doing this operation a few times, clarity of code is the most important. But I think this will give you a good starting point.

Comment: Nice. I didn't think about using `cumsum`.

Comment: BTW, not to rain on your parade, but you are missing indices 1 - 12 as per the requirements.  You also included unnecessary ending indices at the end.  Basically, you have what I have above, but you have the results shifted over.  You have everything else though!

Comment: If you correct your code to produce the correct values, I might add this to my benchmarking results, but I don't expect much of difference between mine and yours as there is very little difference except the `repmat` used by your solution.

Comment: oh, my bad for being careless. Thanks for noticing my mistake. Yeah, I wouldn't expect a difference either.